# What does "<T: Decodable>" mean in method on XCODE?

Tags: xcode

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(filename: String, as type: T.Type) -> T {
    guard let url = self.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil) else {
      fatalError("번들에 \(filename)이 없습니다.")
    }
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
      fatalError("\(url)로부터 데이터를 불러올 수 없습니다.")
    }
    guard let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
      fatalError("데이터 복호화에 실패했습니다.")
    }
    return decodedData
  }
```

In this code, What does '<T: Decodable>' mean in method??
I guess parameter T works protocol, isn't it?
If you have URL that explains this swift grammar, please let me know...:)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer: It is a generic function with a Type Parameter**

---

**In Detail Explanation**

In Swift, we can create a function that can be used with any type of data. Such a function is known as a Generic Function.

Here's how we can create a generic function in Swift:

```
// create a generic function
func displayData<T>(data: T){
  ...
}
```

Here,

We have created a generic function named `displayData()`.

`T` used inside the angle bracket `<>` is called the **type parameter**.

And based on the type of the value passed to the function, the T is replaced by that data type (Int, String, and so on).

For example, if we call this function using:

```
// Code 1
// generic function working with String
displayData(data: "Swift")

// Code 2
// generic function working with Int
displayData(data: 5)
```

**We see in code 1 we have passed a string value, so the placeholder parameter T is automatically replaced by String.**

**Similarly, in code 2 when we pass Int to the generic function the placeholder is replaced by Int.**

Now coming to your case `<T: Decodable>` is a called as **Type Constraints in Swift Generics**

In general, the type parameter can accept any data type (Int, String, Double, ...).

However, if we want to use generics for some specific types (such as accepting data of Decodable types) only, then we can use type constraints.

So <T: Decodable> only accepts the parameters which confirms to the `Decodable` protocol. In your function it accepts `filename` which is a `String` type and this confirms to `Decodable` protocol. Suppose replace `String` with a type which is not confirming to `Decodable` protocol then this function will not work and throw an error.

To know what all type confirms to Decodable protocol have a read at

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable

Under section Relations -> Inherited by topic.